# Fragment dialog issues when dismissing and in onCreate, Fragment$InstantiationException and IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

My app is getting a couple exceptions when I rotate my phone and my progress dialog (DialogFragment) is visible. Not quite sure if I’m following the correct process for creating and dismissing a dialog fragment. If I don’t rotate my phone when the dialog is up, everything is fine.

I create and show the dialog in onCreate()

```
progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"123");
```

and start a background thread to load data from a server. Once the data is loaded I call the dialog’s dismiss() (using **runOnUiThread(() -> {progressDialog.dismiss(); });** to stay thread safe, but note that it never gets called because I rotate and get an exception before the thread finishes). I also call the dialogs dismiss() in onStop().

I see this more often: **androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment myapp.ProgressDialog: could not find Fragment constructor**

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: myapp, PID: 19953
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.GameListActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment myapp.ProgressDialog: could not find Fragment constructor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5802)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5710)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment myapp.ProgressDialog: could not find Fragment constructor
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:563)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:74)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2452)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState(FragmentController.java:196)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:287)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
-->     at myapp.GameListActivity.onCreate(GameListActivity.java:87)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5802) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5710) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: myapp.ProgressDialog.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:548)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:74) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2452) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState(FragmentController.java:196) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:287) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
        at myapp.GameListActivity.onCreate(GameListActivity.java:87) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5802) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5710) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19953 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8624', transport: 'socket'
```

But have also seen **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState** when I’m trying to dismiss a fragment dialog (a progress dialog).

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: myapp, PID: 11658
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {myapp/myapp.GameListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:5125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5775)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5710)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1689)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1729)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:321)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:286)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:270)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:222)
-->     at myapp.GameListActivity.onStop(GameListActivity.java:167)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1474)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:8195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:5117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5775) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5710) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

This is my dialog fragment:

```
public class ProgressDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String TAG="lbp";

    String message;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView progressMessage;

    public ProgressDialog(String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dlgView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress,null);
        progressBar = dlgView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressMessage = dlgView.findViewById(R.id.progressMessage);
        progressMessage.setText(message);

        builder.setView(dlgView);

        return builder.create();
    }

    public void setMessage(CharSequence msg) {
        progressMessage.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your only constructor is `public ProgressDialog(String msg)`, so certainly looks like there's no zero argument constructor, which is a requirement. Why are you calling `dismiss` on a `DialogFragment` in `onStop()`? Dialog fragments automatically handle dismissing/restoring their state.